# Unable to load package in rstudio

Tags: r

RStudio is returning error when trying to load any packages:

> The procedure entry point
>   _ZNKSt7_cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12find_last_ofEP
>   Kcjj could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-.dll.

[image: Screenshot of the error.]

Uninstalling and reinstalling is not helping. Please help.